# Geometry high school math competition question

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with side length $2$.
>   Let the circle with diameter AB be $\gamma$.
>   Consider the two tangents from $C$ to $\gamma$, and let the tangency point closer to $A$ be $D$.
>   Find the area of triangle $CAD$.

I was able to figure out that $CD$ has to be $\sqrt2$. I can not figure out the height of triangle $CAD$.

I am trying to calculate the height from $D$ to $AC.$ Alternatively, if I could find the length of $AD$, then I should also be able to solve problem.

Comment: but you know all three angles are $60$ degrees. if you divide one side in half and then work from there. but maybe you dont even need to divide.

Comment: Can you use trigonometry? If you know $AC$, $CD$ and angle between them, you should be able to find the area. Although I think $CD=1$.

Comment: so, since all sides are of equal size, and from pytagorean theorem: $a^2+b^2=c^2$. then $h^2 = a^2 - (\frac{a}{2})^2$. where $h$ is the height. that will give you a start. but there are more than one way to do find area though.

Comment: bah, I worked on a solution and read wrong (area of $ABC$ instead of $CAD$).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

\begin{align}
S_{ACD}&= 
S_{CDO}+S_{AOD}-S_{AOC}
,\\
S_{CDO}&=\tfrac12|CD|\cdot|OD|=\frac{\sqrt2}2
,\\
S_{AOD}&=\tfrac12|OA|\cdot|OD|\cdot\sin\angle AOD
=\tfrac12\sin\angle OCD
=\tfrac12\cdot\frac{|OD|}{|OC|}
=\frac{\sqrt3}6
,\\
S_{AOC}&=\tfrac12|OA|\cdot|OC|=\frac{\sqrt3}2
,\\
S_{ACD}&=\frac{\sqrt2}2+\frac{\sqrt3}6-
\frac{\sqrt3}2
=\frac{\sqrt2}2-\frac{\sqrt3}3
\approx .1297565117
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $O$ be a center of the circle $\Gamma$.

Thus, by the Pythagoras's theorem 
$$CD^2=CO^2-DO^2=\left(\sqrt3\right)^2-1^2=2$$ and $$CD=\sqrt2.$$
Id est, $$S_{\Delta ACD}=\frac{1}{2}CD\cdot AC\sin\measuredangle ACD=$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt2\cdot2\sin\left(\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-30^{\circ}\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt2\left(\sin\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\cos\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt2\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}.$$

There is a solution without trigonometry.

Let $DK$ be an altitude of $\Delta ADO$.

Thus, since $\Delta OKD\sim\Delta CDO,$ we obtain:
$$\frac{DK}{DO}=\frac{DO}{CO}$$ or
$$\frac{DK}{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3},$$ which gives $$DK=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$ and
$$S_{\Delta ACD}=S_{\Delta ADO}+S_{\Delta OCD}-S_{\Delta ACO}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\cdot1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt2\cdot1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt3\cdot1=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: Thanks for above.  I should have tried to use trigonometry.  My student only knows geometry and the above problem was under geometry section, so I was trying to solve with just geometry.  Above makes much more sense than trying to solve with just geometry.

Comment: @user653261 I added the geometric solution.